# How to increase download speed of larger files in my android phone?

Tags: android, notifications, download, android-remoteview

I am downloading some files from server in users phone
The download is working properly in Kitkat Version phone i.e its getting approx 1-2mbps but above that that the download is very slow .
The code is:-

//The download Code:

```
while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
               int demo = (int)(i * 100L / lengthOfFile);
               if (demo%5==0)
               {
                  updateNotification("TITLE", (int) (i * 100L / lengthOfFile), "TITLE2",1234);
               }

              fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);

}
```

//The notification panel update:-

```
private void updateNotification(String text,int progress,String title,int notify)
```

{

```
notification.contentView.
setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress,100,progress,false);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(notify, notification);
}
```

//Is there something related to notification update method

Comment: Isn't it slow because the internet is slow? There's basically nothing you can do about it

Comment: No the internet is working properly .And while I am using it in Phones below Kitkat its speed is perfect,but when i start downloading in phone having marhsmallow the speed is too slow

Comment: increase buffer, for example

Comment: Have tried increasing buffer but the problem is its working properly in 4.4 but it takes time in 5.0 and above @DEADMC

Comment: Use something like OkHttp that will handle this for you.